# QML Repeater parentness

Tags: c++, qml, qt-quick, qtquick2

Let's say I have 2 types of custom elements - Parent and Child

And can be more then one Parent in the scene

Simple scene looks like this:

```qml
Parent {
    Child {
        id: child1
    }
    Child {
        id: child2
    }
}
```

After scene was loaded I want to initialize all of the Children in Parent class:

```cpp
void InitializeChildren() {
    list = findChildren<Child*>(QString(),Qt::FindChildrenRecursively);
    foreach(Child * child,list) {
        InitChild(this,child);
}
```

But it fails with more complicated scene:

```qml
Parent {
    Rectangle {
        Repeater {
            model: 10
            delegate: Child {
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

just bacause Repeater have no Childs object as children.
So my question - how can I get all Child's objects if I know exactly that they are nested childen of specified Parent?

Answer (score 3):

Alright I figured it out:
There was a change in Qt5 which makes using `findChildren()` for `Repeater` children not usable any more. After having a look at `qquickrepeater.cpp`, it turns out that the `Repeater` calls `QQuickItem::setParentItem()` to the children delegates that get created. Thus the original parents and children remain untouched, but the "visual" parent is the parent of the Repeater.

TLDR:
Do not use `findChildren()` in Qt5 to browse through the item scene graph. Instead, use something like the following:

```
void getAllSearchTypes(QQuickItem *parent, QList<SearchType *> &list) {

 QList<QQuickItem *> children = parent->childItems();   
  foreach (QQuickItem *item, children) {
    SearchType *searchObject = dynamic_cast<SearchType *>(item);
    if (seachObject) list.append(searchObject);
    // call recursively and browse through the whole scene graph
    getAllSearchTypes(item, list);
 } 
}
```

And call the function like that:

```
QList<SearchType *> list;
getAllSearchTypes(rootItem, list);
// list now contains all objects of type SearchType, recursively searched children of rootItem
```

Replace `SearchType` with the C++ type you are looking for.

**NOTE:** the relevant change to `findChildren()`, is that you need to call `childItems()` and not `children()`. Ideally, there would be a template function in `QQuickItem` for example called `findChildItems()` in future Qt versions, which does the above recursive search internally.

Comment: +1 Thank you, this worked perfectly. I think there's no better way of doing it than this. Probably this should be the accepted answer...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parsing the repeater you can set the model in you c++ code:

```
Parent {
    Rectangle {
        Repeater {
            model: childModel
            delegate: Child {
                 Text { text: childValue }
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

In your c++:

```
QList<QObject*> m_childModel;
void InitializeChildren() {
    this->m_childModel.append(new Child("value 1"));
    this->m_childModel.append(new Child("value 2"));
    this->m_scene->rootContext()->setContextProperty("childModel", QVariant::fromValue(m_childModel));
}
```

you also need to do the `setContextProperty` before loading the root QML file.

And the `Child` declaration:

```
class Child : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Child(QString value) : m_value(value) {}
    Q_PROPERTY(QString  childValue    READ getChildValue  WRITE setChildValue    NOTIFY childValueUpdated)
    // Other properties... 

    QString getChildValue()    const { return m_value; }
    void setChildValue(const QString &value)
    {
        if (value == m_value)
            return;
        m_value = value;
        emit childValueUpdated();
    }

signals:
    void childValueUpdated();

private:
    QString m_value;

}
```

Comment: Thank you @Kirween for the answer. May be I was not so clear but my purpose is to make some flexible structure in QML not in C++. Appending new Child have to be transparent for user in common QML style as nested block. Child can be inside Rectangle ot Item or any else QML node. But all these elements are children of Parent, not necessarily direct child of Parent. may be child of child... I need to fetch from this heap only Child nodes but all of them